# JPEG encoding error for any image size larger than 16x8 or 8x16

Tags: c, image, jpeg, huffman-code, jfif

Currently I'm developing a jpeg encoder for a university project. The image has fixed size and the encoder uses fixed quantization and Huffman tables for baseline process. First, my code reads 32-bit RGBx values from SDRAM, converts to YCbCr color space, normalizes each channel to 0 and writes back. Then, it starts doing DCT on 8x8 blocks and writes entropy encoded data to SDRAM. This process is done using C and then a Python code creates a file with appropriate JFIF markers and the entropy encoded data. Last of all, OS default jpeg decoder is used to view the image by simple double-clicking on it.

My code works with 8x8, 8x16 and 16x8 images but not with 16x16 nor the actual size of the image used in project. Below you may see 16x16 example.

[image: 16x16 input image] 16x16 Input

[image: 16x16 output image] 16x16 Output

However, on stackoverflow it seems different than compared to my OS' default decoder. Below is how it looks like on macOS Preview application.

[image]

I believe my problem is due to either the markers in JFIF or some kind of an algorithm error.

I would be very glad if anyone with experience in jpeg can help me out.

Kind regards

Comment: Can you post binary dump of your encoded jpegs? (You can encode them to hex and post on some text "pasting site" or in your question)

Comment: https://justpaste.it/171lj This is the hex of my output image

Comment: https://justpaste.it/171m3 This is the python code to create the jpeg file

Comment: It's hard to tell what is going on here. Do you get any errors when you decode? Are you subsampling?

Comment: I don't really decode. I leave that part to my OS' default codec. All I do is generate raw encoded bit stream per channel. Put together them with appropriate JPEG markers and save as .jpeg file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written a jpeg codec. It's maintained at https://github.com/MalcolmMcLean/babyxrc however whilst you're welcome to take a look, or even use it, that doesn't really answer your question.

JPEG is based on 16x16 blocks for chromiance and 8x8 blocks for luminance. So it's not surprising that an initial version of your software crashes after the first 16x16 block. It's just a routine programming error. If you can't find it by reading the JEG spec, fire up an editor, and create a flat 32x32 image. Then look at the binary and see where it differs from yours.

Here's my loadscan for no sub-sampling

```
static int loadscanYuv111(JPEGHEADER *hdr, unsigned char *buff, FILE *fp)
{
  short lum[64];
  short Cb[64];
  short Cr[64];
  BITSTREAM *bs;
  int i;
  int ii;
  int iii;
  int iv;
  int diffdc = 0;
  int dcb = 0;
  int dcr = 0;
  int actableY;
  int actableCb;
  int actableCr;
  int dctableY;
  int dctableCb;
  int dctableCr;
  int count = 0;
  int target;
  int luminance;
  int red;
  int green;
  int blue;

  actableY = hdr->useac[0];
  actableCb = hdr->useac[1];
  actableCr = hdr->useac[2];
  dctableY = hdr->usedc[0];
  dctableCb = hdr->usedc[1];
  dctableCr = hdr->usedc[2];

  bs = bitstream(fp);

  for(i=0;i<hdr->height;i+=8)
    for(ii=0;ii<hdr->width;ii+=8)
    {
      if(hdr->dri && (count % hdr->dri) == 0 && count > 0 )
      {
        readmarker(bs);
        diffdc = 0;
        dcb = 0;
        dcr = 0;
      }

      getblock(lum, hdr->dctable[dctableY], hdr->actable[actableY], bs);
      lum[0] += diffdc;
      diffdc = lum[0];

      for(iv=0;iv<64;iv++)
        lum[iv] *= hdr->qttable[hdr->useq[0]][iv];
      unzigzag(lum);
      idct8x8(lum);

      getblock(Cb, hdr->dctable[dctableCb], hdr->actable[actableCb], bs);
      Cb[0] += dcb;
      dcb = Cb[0];

      for(iv=0;iv<64;iv++)
        Cb[iv] *= hdr->qttable[hdr->useq[1]][iv];
      unzigzag(Cb);
      idct8x8(Cb);

      getblock(Cr, hdr->dctable[dctableCr], hdr->actable[actableCr], bs);
      Cr[0] += dcr;
      dcr = Cr[0];

      for(iv=0;iv<64;iv++)
        Cr[iv] *= hdr->qttable[hdr->useq[2]][iv];
      unzigzag(Cr);
      idct8x8(Cr);

      for(iii=0;iii<8;iii++)
      {
        if( i + iii >= hdr->height)
          break;
        for(iv=0;iv<8;iv++)
        {
          if(ii + iv >= hdr->width)
            break;
          target = (i + iii) * hdr->width * 3 + (ii + iv) * 3;
          luminance = lum[iii*8+iv]/64 + 128;
          red = (int) (luminance + 1.402  * Cr[iii*8+iv]/64);
          green = (int) (luminance - 0.34414 * Cb[iii*8+iv]/64 - 0.71414 * Cr[iii*8+iv]/64);
          blue = (int) (luminance + 1.772  * Cb[iii*8+iv]/64);
          red = clamp(red, 0, 255);
          green = clamp(green, 0, 255);
          blue = clamp(blue, 0, 255);
          buff[target] = red;
          buff[target+1] = green;
          buff[target+2] = blue;
        }
      }

      count++;
    }

  killbitstream(bs);
  if(loadeoi(fp) == 0)
    return 0;

  return -1;
}
```

As you can see, the data is interleaved. 
However if you got that wrong it would create a peculiar image of the correct dimensions, not a smaller image than expected.

Comment: 16x16 for chromiance is default subsampling type; is it possible to set "no subsampling" in JPEG ([4:4:4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_subsampling#4:4:4))?

Comment: I don't use any subsampling for chrominance channels. Do I have to?

Comment: It's normal to subsample. Not setting up the blocks correctly could well be your problem.

Comment: If I understood the specification correctly, when there is no subsampling (thus, non-interleaved) each scan should contain one image component with entropy-encoded data starting from top left 8x8 block to bottom right block. The blocks are separated by EOB symbols. Each scan's entropy encoded segment is stuffed by 1s to nearest byte.